# Can I view Java serialized object for debug?

Tags: java, serialization

I came into a problem where one of my `HashMap` members turns into null after serialization. It turns to be a nasty thing to debug. During the process, I noticed that I'd really like to have some kind of debug view of the serialized files. Because in the end, the serialized file structure must look like this:

```
package.MyClass
    propName = package2.MyClass2 /**nested class data here**/;
    propName2 = java.lang.Integer 666;
```

And so on, simply put, the classes are not needed for human reading of the data. Is there any way to half-unserialize the data without turning them into Java instances so that I could output the contents into console?

Comment: I'm confused at your question. If you want to view a serialized object, unserialize it and view it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The object is errorneous, or one of the classes is missing.

Comment: Simplify your program and debug. If still no solution, then simplify some more and debug, iteratively until a solution is achieved.

Comment: Classic XY problem. Solve the original problem, not the problem you have when trying to debug the original problem. I suggest you probably need to have a look at [`ObjectOutputStream.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()), or its `writeUnshared()` method.

Comment: @EJP I already solved it. But this is a thing I want to do very often. It would also help a lot with reverse engineering other java applications.

Comment: @ejp Another good picture of how wrong you are: right now, my program produces serialized file that can't be unserialized. If I got good answer to this question (asked for different reason) I could debug this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Use a hex editor.  It's a fair bit of manual work though so you might be better off listening to Hovercraft and EJP.  But if you're anything like me you can't resist looking under the covers at least once.

Comment: And what will using the hex editor tell you? What usable information can be gained from this?

Comment: I opened the files using hex edit of course, but seen nothing I could understand. I was hoping that there's a way to use Java libraries to parse the binary file without loading up the classes and generally constructing java objects from serialized data.

Comment: @TomášZato You need to read the hex dump in association with the [Object Serialization Stream Protocol Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html), obviously, but it's not easy, as the content for any object can be dependent on the implementation of the class.